# First-order inhomogeneous PDE in general form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am solving the initial value problem:

$$u_t +u_x = -\sigma(x)u+m(x), \quad u(x,0)=\phi(x), \quad u(0,t)=\gamma(t)$$

I need to get solution like this:

\begin{equation*}
u(x,t)=\phi(x-t) e^{-\int_{x-t}^{x} -\sigma(s)ds}+\int_{x-t}^{x} m(\tau)e^{-\int_{\tau}^{x} -\sigma(s)ds}d\tau, \quad t<x
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
u(x,t)=\gamma(t-x) e^{-\int_{0}^{x} -\sigma(s)ds}+\int_{0}^{x} m(\tau)e^{-\int_{\tau}^{x} -\sigma(s)ds}d\tau, \quad x<t
\end{equation*}

I have tried to use characteristic line G: $$x(\tau)=x+\tau, \quad t(\tau)=t+\tau$$
And i also know, that on this line:
$$\frac{du(x+\tau,t+\tau)}{d\tau} = -\sigma(x+\tau)u(x+\tau,t+\tau) + m(x+\tau)$$

I can solve it firstly like homogeneous problem:
$$\frac{du(x+\tau,t+\tau)}{u(x+\tau,t+\tau)} = -\sigma(x+\tau)d\tau$$
By integrating it $\tau$ from -t to zero for first case x>t.

And i got $$u(x,t)=u(x-t,0)e^{-\int_{-t}^{0} -\sigma(x+\tau) d\tau}$$

So I don't know what I should to do next. Because I don't have some const to use method of constant variance. Please help me complete the task.

Comment: Did you mean to write $-\sigma(x)+m(t)$ rather than $-\sigma(x)+m(x)$? If both are functions of $x$, you could just replace them by a single function.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark Sorry, I forgot multiply sigma to u. So the correct task is $u_t+u_x = -\sigma(x)u+m(x)$

Comment: OK, that makes more sense!

Comment: You asked the same question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4843699/general-solution-first-order-inhomogeneous-pde. Please delete one of them.

Comment: @Gonçalo it’s done.

Comment: You might notice that the integrating factor $e^{\int \sigma(x) dx}$ simplifies the sum of the last and first terms on the LHS and RHS, respectively 

$$e^{\int \sigma(x) dx}(u_{x} + \sigma(x) u) = (e^{\int \sigma(x) dx} u)_{x}$$

so multiply the PDE by the integrating factor

$$(e^{\int \sigma(x) dx} u)_{t} + (e^{\int \sigma(x) dx} u)_{x} = m(x) e^{\int \sigma(x) dx}$$

then define $e^{\int \sigma(x) dx} u = v$ and use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

Comment: @MatthewCassell That's interesting and helpful. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_t +u_x = -\sigma(x)u+m(x), \quad u(x,0)=\phi(x), \quad u(0,t)=\gamma(t)$$

Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{-\sigma(x)u+m(x)}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1}$ :
$$x-t=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{-\sigma(x)u+m(x)}\quad\implies\quad\frac{du}{dx}=-\sigma(x)u+m(x)$

This is a first order linear ODE which is solved thanks to classical method :
$$u=c_2\exp\left(-\int_{0}^x \sigma(\xi)d\xi \right) +\exp\left(-\int_{0}^x \sigma(\xi)d\xi \right)\int_{0}^x \exp\left(\int_{0}^\zeta\sigma(\xi)d\xi  \right)m(\zeta)d\zeta $$
The genaral solution of the PDE from implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=F(x-t)\exp\left(-\int_{0}^x \sigma(\xi)d\xi \right) +\exp\left(-\int_{0}^x \sigma(\xi)d\xi \right)\int_{0}^x \exp\left(\int_{0}^\zeta\sigma(\xi)d\xi  \right)m(\zeta)d\zeta} $$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the specified conditions).

Conditions : $u(x,0)=\phi(x), \quad u(0,t)=\gamma(t)$

One observes that the two conditions are not necessarily compatible at $(0,0)$. Compatibility would implies $u(0,0)=\phi(0)=\gamma(0)$. For any $\phi(x)$ and $\gamma(t)$ the solution will be a piecewise function. $u(x,t)$ should have two different forms in the two areas separated by the boundary $x-t=0$ : The functions $F$ will be not the same.

In order to determine the two functions $F$ one have successively to put the conditions into the above general solution. After a function $F(x)$ and a different $F(t)$ are determined one have to put them back into the general solution with the argument $(x-t)$ instead of $x$ or $t$. Certainly some transformations (possibly arduous) will be necessary to go to the expected forms of equations.